# SQL Get the interval 9:32 to 10:02 as 9:30 interval and 10:03 and 10:32 as 10:00

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL and I need to get this result but I dont know how. What I need is to get which interval does a time exist. Please refer to the example below

```
     ---------------------- 
    | Time   |    Interval|
    ----------------------|
    | 9:03   |    9:00    |
    | 9:02   |    8:30    |
    | 9:32   |    9:00    |
    | 9:33   |    9:30    |
    -----------------------
```

Sample interval matrix

```
    ----------------------------- 
    | Interval   |    Time       |
    -----------------------------|
    | 9:00   |    9:02 - 9:31:59 |
    | 9:30   |    9:32 - 10:01:59|
    | 10:00  |    10:02- 10:31:59|
    ----------------------- ------
```

So basically `9:03 - 9:32` exist in `9:00` oclock interval and `9:33 - 10:02` exist in 9:30 interval

I have this query

```
      SELECT CONVERT(time(7),DATEADD(MINUTE,(DATEPART(MINUTE, '10:32:00') / 
             30)*30,(DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, '10:32:00'), 0))))
```

but this is the farthest I can come up, the result should be `10:00` interval. You can point me in the right direction or give me some tips

Comment: I am slightly confused by your sample data, because `Interval` isn't really an interval, it's just a single point in time (or am I missing something?)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen what do you mean single point in time?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you can say it's a single point in time. For example `9:02-9:32` belongs to `9:00` data.

Comment: Can you edit your question and show a third mock column which shows what the actual intervals are for each row?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen please refer to the sample now

Comment: One last question: What is your exact expected output, based on the sample table you showed us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will give you what you need:

```
declare @testtable table (thedate time )

insert into @testtable values ( '09:03'),   ('09:02'),    ('09:32'),    ('09:33')

select 
thedate,
case when datepart(minute,thedate) between 0 and 2  then dateadd(minute, -30,cast(cast(datepart(hour,thedate) as varchar)+':00' as time))
             when datepart(minute,thedate) between 3 and 32 then cast(cast(datepart(hour,thedate) as varchar)+':00' as time)
             else dateadd(minute, +30,cast(cast(datepart(hour,thedate) as varchar)+':00' as time))
            end
from @testtable
```

which produces:

```
09:03:00.0000000    09:00:00.0000000
09:02:00.0000000    08:30:00.0000000
09:32:00.0000000    09:00:00.0000000
09:33:00.0000000    09:30:00.0000000
```

Comment: You give the right output but the code is not flexible

Comment: From the explanation given, this was the best I could decipher, more than willing to adjust with input

Answer (score 1):

The following solution uses `DATEDIFF` with `MINUTE` against an offset of `00:02` to correct the difference first, then truncates the time to 30 min intervals by operating the minutes as *integers* and doing `/ 30 * 30` and finally convert back the result to `TIME`.

```
DECLARE @Times TABLE (ClockTime TIME)

INSERT INTO @Times (ClockTime)
VALUES 
    ('08:57'),
    ('08:58'),
    ('08:59'),
    ('09:00'),
    ('09:01'),
    ('09:02'),
    ('09:03'),
    ('09:05'),
    ('09:31'),
    ('09:31:59'),
    ('09:32'),
    ('10:32'),
    ('23:02'),
    ('23:03'),
    ('23:31:15')


SELECT
    T.ClockTime,
    MinutesMinus2 = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '00:02', T.ClockTime),
    MinutesMinus2On30Intervals = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '00:02', T.ClockTime) / 30 * 30,
    MinutesMinus2On30IntervalsAsTime = CONVERT(
        TIME, 
        DATEADD(
            MINUTE, 
            DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '00:02', T.ClockTime) / 30 * 30, -- MinutesMinus2On30Intervals
            0))
FROM
    @Times AS T
```

Results:

```
+------------------+---------------+----------------------------+----------------------------------+
|    ClockTime     | MinutesMinus2 | MinutesMinus2On30Intervals | MinutesMinus2On30IntervalsAsTime |
+------------------+---------------+----------------------------+----------------------------------+
| 08:57:00.0000000 |           535 |                        510 | 08:30:00.0000000                 |
| 08:58:00.0000000 |           536 |                        510 | 08:30:00.0000000                 |
| 08:59:00.0000000 |           537 |                        510 | 08:30:00.0000000                 |
| 09:00:00.0000000 |           538 |                        510 | 08:30:00.0000000                 |
| 09:01:00.0000000 |           539 |                        510 | 08:30:00.0000000                 |
| 09:02:00.0000000 |           540 |                        540 | 09:00:00.0000000                 |
| 09:03:00.0000000 |           541 |                        540 | 09:00:00.0000000                 |
| 09:05:00.0000000 |           543 |                        540 | 09:00:00.0000000                 |
| 09:31:00.0000000 |           569 |                        540 | 09:00:00.0000000                 |
| 09:31:59.0000000 |           569 |                        540 | 09:00:00.0000000                 |
| 09:32:00.0000000 |           570 |                        570 | 09:30:00.0000000                 |
| 10:32:00.0000000 |           630 |                        630 | 10:30:00.0000000                 |
| 23:02:00.0000000 |          1380 |                       1380 | 23:00:00.0000000                 |
| 23:03:00.0000000 |          1381 |                       1380 | 23:00:00.0000000                 |
| 23:31:15.0000000 |          1409 |                       1380 | 23:00:00.0000000                 |
+------------------+---------------+----------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

You could also parameterize the offset with a `TIME` variable in case your your time bias changes:

```
DECLARE @TimeOffset TIME = '00:02'

SELECT
    Interval = CONVERT(
        TIME, 
        DATEADD(
            MINUTE, 
            DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @TimeOffset, T.ClockTime) / 30 * 30,
            0))
FROM
    @Times AS T
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that i have change the `interval` time range string to start and end time. If you data is in string, do consider converting to 2 separate time data type. Else you will need to perform some string parsing in the query

Once the data is in the right format, the query is simply a `INNER JOIN`

```
declare @sample table 
(
      [Time]        time(0)
)

insert into @sample 
values ('09:03'),   
       ('09:02'),    
       ('09:32'),     
       ('09:33')

declare @interval table
(
    [Interval]      time(0),
    [Time_Start]    time(0),
    [Time_End]      time(0)
)

insert into @interval
values  ('09:00', '09:02', '09:31:59'),
        ('09:30', '09:32', '10:01:59'),
        ('10:00', '10:02', '10:31:59')

select  s.Time, i.Interval
from    @sample s
        inner join @interval i  on  s.Time  between i.Time_Start and i.Time_End
```

Answer (score 0):

I give the answer to others for the idea but I think this is more clean and easy to understand

```
DECLARE @date time = '07-04-2019 10:32:00'
SELECT CONVERT(time(7),DATEADD(MINUTE,(DATEPART(MINUTE, 
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(MINUTE, @date) = 31 THEN DATEADD(minute,-2,@date) WHEN DATEPART(MINUTE, @date) = 1 THEN DATEADD(minute,-2,@date) ELSE @date END
      ) / 30)*30,(DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, CASE WHEN DATEPART(MINUTE,@date) = 1 THEN DATEADD(HOUR,-1,@date) ELSE @date END), 0))))
```